# Mysql запрос к двум таблицам

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть две таблицы, во всех таблицах есть поле `seo_url`. Нужно как-то объединить эти таблицы и получить значение (`name`, `text`, ..) по `seo_url`. Написал такой запрос:

```
SELECT * 
FROM news INNER JOIN category 
WHERE category.seo_url = 'company_news' OR news.seo_url = 'company_news'
```

Но получаю результат в виде сложенных двух таблиц(вообще неправильно), а нужно получить например, если есть подходящий `seo_url` в таблице `news`, то берем значение оттуда.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM news JOIN category WHERE category.seo_url =  news.seo_url`

Comment: видимо нужен union. Хотя не факт, потому что задача описана не понятно

Comment: Покажите пример, если не получается объяснить словами.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT U.name, U.text, U.seo_url
FROM (
   SELECT name, text, seo_url FROM news
   UNION ALL
   SELECT name, text, seo_url FROM category
) AS U
WHERE U.seo_url = 'company_news';
```